# Windows Server Resource Monitor details are all blank

Tags: windows

I'm not a Windows admin, just a DBA using Windows. I don't know how it would be related, but we just did an in-place upgrade from SQL 2016 to SQL 2019. To be honest, I am not sure whether this was happening before the upgrade.

I'm seeing an odd issue on Windows Server 2016 Standard for this host. When I open Task Manager, I see the resource overview, but when I open Resource Monitor, all of the detail areas are blank (screenshot attached here).

I have tried the following, without a resolution:

- Restarting the server.
- Starting Resource Monitor using Start > Run > resmon.
- Googling the issue. Nothing exactly matches what I am seeing.

Does anyone know what would cause this and/or how to fix it?

Thanks for any help.

[image: Resource Monitor shows no details]

Comment: And if you run it elevated?

Comment: Thanks @GregAskew - I got the same result. I suspect there is something out of whack at the OS level. I'll mention these details to our Windows administrators. Thanks again.